# javascript: работа с указателями на память или типизирование объектов

Tags: javascript, memory

Появилась вот такая потребность: Имеется последовательность из N байтов, где, к примеру, первые четыре являются числом, далее идет строка, длинною в m симовлов и т.д..

Могу ли я в javascript как в с++ указать указатель со смещением, для того чтобы считать данные?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы [это](http://javascript.svoisait.ru/operator.shtml#bitwiseop) (побитовые операторы) имеете в виду?

Comment: Практически оно. Как же я сам этого не нашел, хотя всегда использовал! Спасибо.